# Do not count back of the title page in Page number in two side book style file

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, thesis

I am writing a thesis in which after the title page, the next page coming back to the title page. If I put `\cleardoublepage\null`, the next page comes to the right place but the page numbering starts from the back page of title. It disturbs the odd/even page setting of the thesis. 
Please help, how can I put a title back page empty which is not countable and the page numbering will start from the next page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{Classes/CUEDthesisPSnPDF} \usepackage{StyleFiles/watermark} 
\onehalfspacing 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\frontmatter 
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\include{Certificate/certificate} 
\include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement} 
\include{Abstract/abstract} 
\include{Preface/preface} 
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\listoftables 
\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname} 
\printnomenclature[4cm] 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature} 
\mainmatter 
\include{Chapter1/chapter1} 
\include{Chapter2/chapter2} 
\include{Chapter3/chapter3} 
\include{Chapter4/chapter4} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, please show us some code that we can see what you are doing. Which document class do you use, how is the titlepage created, which options have you used etc.  All related information to your problem would help ...

Comment: normally a titlepage is not a cover page so it's countable: it is empty but number 1 next page is number 2. Now you can try `\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}\null\newpage`

Comment: @user3132983: So where can the community find access to `CUEDthesisPSnPDF.cls` - your `\documentclass`?

Comment: Since that template is distributed at different places in different versions and the example wouldn't be compilabel without the files i vote to close as unclear. Additionally, i don't understand the question.